# Best practice for translating app description for local apps on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing some local (country specific) apps published on Google Play. For example an app in Spanish, targeting Spanish speaking audience only.

I experience that the search algorithm on Google Play does not prioritize my app. Even if I search for the app name, my app does not show up in the top 250 search results even though the search string is the same as my application name an no other applications share the same name.

Also, when I search in non-english languages, I often get results from English apps where the description seems to be auto-translated.

What is the best practice when it comes to translations of the app descriptions? Should I provide an English translation of the app description (right now I have Spanish only)? Does this affect searches in Spanish language in any way?